# UITableView Edit Mode works fine but delete button does not do anything

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewcelleditcontrol

[image: Edit mode image]

Edit mode works just fine and CanMoveRowAtIndexPath also works fine since I can reorder the cells, but the delete button doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    private func setUpDataSource() {
        dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<StockDetailsSectionModel>(
            animationConfiguration: AnimationConfiguration(insertAnimation: .right, reloadAnimation: .bottom, deleteAnimation: .left),
            configureCell: configureCell,
            canEditRowAtIndexPath: canEditRowAtIndexPath,
            canMoveRowAtIndexPath: canMoveRowAtIndexPath
        )
    }

    private func bindNavigationBar() {
        editBarButton.rx.tap.asDriver()
            .map { [unowned self] in self.tableView.isEditing }
            .drive(onNext: { [unowned self] result in self.tableView.setEditing(!result, animated: true) })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }


}

extension StockListController {
    private var configureCell: RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<StockDetailsSectionModel>.ConfigureCell {
        return { _, tableView, indexPath, model in
            let cell: StockListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StockListCell
            cell.stockPrice = model
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    private var canEditRowAtIndexPath: RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<StockDetailsSectionModel>.CanEditRowAtIndexPath {
        return { [unowned self] _, _ in
            if self.tableView.isEditing {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var canMoveRowAtIndexPath: RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<StockDetailsSectionModel>.CanMoveRowAtIndexPath {
        return { _, _ in
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: How to delete cell in tableview using RxSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050486/ios-how-to-delete-cell-in-tableview-using-rxswift)

Comment: No... I don't think this is a datasource problem, because CanMoveRowAtIndexPath works. I assume this happens because I am using a programmatic UI not storyboard. And something is preventing tableview to show the delete button on the right side.

Comment: What do you mean with: 'is preventing tableview to show the delete button'? I can see the delete button on the left side. And you stated: 'but the delete button doesn't do anything'.

Comment: @burnsi Once the red button is clicked it should make a red delete area to appear, which deletes the row on click. Basically there is no click action at all on that red circular minus button.

Comment: By the way I solved this issue by not using RxDataSource Library. I don't know why it doesn't work, but using standard UITableViewDataSource solves this issue.